# How to get the base class from this example with Clang ?

Tags: c++, clang

Here is a very basic sample of code, and what I would like to have :

```
class B{
    // Implementation of class B
};
class D : public B{
    // Implementation of class D
};
int main(){
    try{
        // Code for try statement
    }
    catch(D & d){
        // Handler for D 
    } 
    catch(B & b){
        // Handler for B 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Currently I am able to get the [CXXRecordDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html) of class B and class D, in handlers (I can get them from the `getCaughtType` method in `CXXCatchStmt` class).

What I would like to do is to be able to access `CXXRecordDecl` of class B from class D, since we have `class D : public B`.

I have tried the following methods available in `class CXXRecordDecl` on my `CXXRecordDecl` of `class D`:

- [getCanonicalDecl()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html#acf7ca8f579ad3e20a49d9d0bf925b3d3) : returns class D
- [getInstantiatedFromMemberClass()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html#ac45cd075737b8802e8b1733037dc1168) : returns **nullptr**
- [getDefinition()](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html#a2bd01ec3ffb06b176ced1bfc31abd99f) : returns class D

I'm out of ideas right now. Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: The [`CXXRecordDecl::bases_begin`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html#a830448d054e3dca2db6851bd4605492c) function seems a good candidate to start with.

Comment: I'm testing right know. i'll tell you ASAP

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's perfect. You can make it an answer, I'll gladly approve it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the implementation of the answer given by **Joachim Pileborg** in comments.

```
bool VisitCXXTryStmt(CXXTryStmt * tryStmt){
    int nbCatch = tryStmt->getNumHandlers(); 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbCatch ; i++){
        if(tryStmt->getHandler(i)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl() == nullptr){
            cout << "The caught type is not a class" << endl; 
        }
        else{
            cout << "Class caught : " << tryStmt->getHandler(i)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl()->getNameAsString() << endl;
        } 
        if(tryStmt->getHandler(i)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl()->bases_begin() == nullptr){
            cout << "This class is the base class" << endl; 
        }
        else{
            cout << "Base class caught : " << tryStmt->getHandler(i)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl()->bases_begin()->getType().getAsString() << endl;
        } 
        cout << "\n \n END OF LOOP \n \n" << endl; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Yields the following output for the example given in the question :

*Class caught : D*

*Base class caught : class B*

*END OF LOOP*

*Class caught : B*

*This class is the base class*

*END OF LOOP*