# Why does Clang returns sometimes nullptr, sometimes what I want?

Tags: c++, clang

This question indirectly follows [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360120/how-to-get-the-base-class-from-this-example-with-clang), in case you want a wider look on what I want to make.

So, basically, I want to distinguish handlers catching common classes, and handlers catching classes which are, indeed, child classes.

So, with the previous provided link, I found a way to know if I'm dealing with a simple class, or with a child class, but, I can't get the `CXXRecordDecl` of the base associated with my child class.

For instance, here is a piece of code :

```
class B{
    // Implementation of class B
};
class D : public B{
    // Implementation of class D
};
int main(){
    try{
        // Code for try statement
    }
    catch(D & d){
        // Handler for D 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

with the following piece of code, I am able to get the `CXXRecordDecl` of `class D` :

```
bool VisitCXXTryStmt(CXXTryStmt * tryStmt){
    CXXRecordDecl * child_class = tryStmt->getHandler(0)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl();
    return true; 
}
```

This works fine, I can have the `CXXRecordDecl` through the `QualType`. 
So I innocently thought this would work aswell to get the base class :

```
bool VisitCXXTryStmt(CXXTryStmt * tryStmt){
    CXXRecordDecl * base_class = tryStmt->getHandler(0)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl()->bases_begin()->getType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl();
    return true;
}
```

But this returns nullptr. However, if I'm executing this line :

```
cout << tryStmt->getHandler(0)->getCaughtType().getTypePtr()->getPointeeCXXRecordDecl()->bases_begin()->getType().getAsString() << endl;
```

I have the output I want (*class B*).

So, why can I have the class declaration in one case, but not in the other ??

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to help you. However, I can tell you that the compiler are very rarely wrong.

Comment: Does it happen in other compilers? If so, could you upload a compiling version on up on [this online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) showcasing the problem?

Comment: I don't want to compile with Clang, I use it for parsing purposes, and I don't understand why does the same method yields a CXXRecordDecl and nullptr when assigned a QualType of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a method to get the `CXXRecordDecl` I wanted.

I don't have a plausible explanation for that, but :

- In the first case, using method [getPointeeCXXRecordDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html#a2196920ba6a8f9e9dfa18945722d807a) returns the wanted `CXXRecordDecl`.
- In the second case, using method [getAsCXXRecordDecl](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html#a7dc6c3dbc192ad98871c3cc484376b9a) returns the wanted `CXXRecordDecl`.

These statements can not be interchanged (using `getAsCXXRecordDecl` in first case returns `nullptr` whereas using `getPointeeCXXRecordDecl` in second case returns also `nullptr`.

I don't have an explanation, but it does work as I wanted to, even if that bothers me a little not to know exactly why :/

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but since I stumbled upon it I figured I should clarify: you're conflating `getPointeeCXXRecordDecl` and `getAsCXXRecordDecl`. The former is only used for pointer and reference types, which `D & d` defines in your `catch`. But the base class of `class D` (stored inside of the `CXXBaseSpecifier` you're accessing via `bases_begin()`) is not a pointer or reference type, it's just a boring record type. So that's why you need to use `getAsCXXRecordDecl` in one case but not the other.