# Appropriate AST Matcher for class parent declaration

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

Given a class hierarchy:

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public C {};
```

I'm trying to refactor class C to inherit from class B rather than class A.  I can easily get the definition statement using a `recordDecl`:

```
recordDecl(hasName("C"), isDefinition()).bind("MyClass")
```

With an associated MatchCallback, I can `dump()` the class to verify it matched the right node.  However I have not found a way to bind instead to the `public A` or, even better, just the `A`.

What would be an appropriate AST Matcher to capture either `public A` or `A` for class C?

**EDIT:**

The output of `clang -ast-dump` filtered for class C in this situation would show something similar to the following:

```
CXXRecordDecl [address] <line numbers> <loc> class C definition
|- public 'class A'
|- CXXRecordDecl [address 2] <columns> <loc> implicit referenced class C
```

It's as if there is no AST Node type to represent parent class declarations in the ast-dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25363529/2796361) providing some context for how to drill down.  Notably, one tutorial suggested using `RecordDecl` in the match handler for the returned node vs. this reference using `CXXRecordDecl`.  So if we output each base in the match handler:

```
if (const CXXRecord *entityBase = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::CXXRecordDecl>("entityBase")) {
    for (auto &p : entityBase->bases()) {
        p.dump();
    }
}
```

We find that the reference to class A is `RecordType` which is referred to by a `CXXRecord`.  However using `clang-query`, I did not find a way to chain `match recordType(...)` with anything conducive to pulling just `public A` or `A`.  Instead, the solution became something similar to this:

```
std::string qual = "public ";
std::string parentName = "A";
std::string parentType = "class " + parentName;
if (0 == parentType.compare(p.getType().getAsString())) {
    Replacement Rep(*(Result.SourceManager),
        p.getLocStart().getLocWithOffset(qual.length()),
        parentName.length(),
        "B");
    Replace->insert(Rep);
}
```

I'm not marking this as the answer yet just in case someone has a way to use recordType to snag the base class reference directly rather than iterating and checking base class type names, as shown above.